# How to publish assets using web-api

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using a MVC Web Api server application for generating client data. In addition, I want to publish a collection of JavaScript, XAP (Silverlight) and XML files to my client-side application. Currently, I have a project structure in which those directories are mixed through my .Net implementation code (what I do not like), as the client app uses URIs to request these files can not be changed. Nevertheless, I want to separate the client data from the server application implementation in a different folder.

Therefore, is there a way to store the client data in a separate folder, e.g.

- /clientdata/JavaScript
- /clientdata/XAP
- /clientdata/XML
- /clientdata/...

in my project, while still being able to access these files using URIs like

- /JavaScript
- /XAP/
- /XML/

Which are the URLs used by the client app and again can not be easily changed.

This is the main method of my Global.asax

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: string.Empty,
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "TCMsimulator.Controllers" }
        );

        var config = new Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.HttpConfiguration();

        RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<ResourcesService>("resources/", config);    
        RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<PublicResourcesService>("publicresources/",config);
        RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<MonitorService>("monitor/", config);
```

Is there a way to add a folder redirect to the routing table, such that a virtual folder in the URI is redirected to a filesystem folder? Like can be done using ModRewrite in Apache? It seems like a simple problem, but I have not found a solution to it in Web Api.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If these directories only contain files and not Web Api generated output, you should probably ignore the routes to the directories and make sure the requests for them run outside of Web Api, like regular static files that are served from IIS (e.g. images).

Comment: Actually, I use ASP.NET development server 4.0 instead of IIS, would that also work?

Comment: I can't see why not, any server that can serve static content should do.

Comment: Yes, but how? If the files are located outside the wwwroot then some configuration is needed to map a URL prefix to the files directory (typically ModRewrite in Apache). I'm thinking of switching to IIS, however.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using Attribute Routing. It is much more understandable. You can see examples of multiple routes mapped to a single resource.

http://attributerouting.net/

Comment: But can it be used to route to static content, while also allowing wildcards in the URL? The examples show how e.g. to map to "MVC Areas" and Controllers but I don't see an example to route to static content. Can you point me to a direct example?